# Is it acceptable to use std::merge for overlapping ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, merge, stl

I have an algorithm which requires applying set union many times to growing sets of integers. For efficiency I represent the sets as sorted vectors, so that their union can be obtained by merging them.

A classical way to merge two sorted vectors is this:

```
void inmerge(vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b) {
  a.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
  std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(a));
  std::inplace_merge(a.begin(), a.end() - b.size(), a.end());
}
```

Unfortunately, `std::inplace_merge` appears to be much slower than `std::sort` in this case, because of the allocation overhead. The fastest way is to use `std::merge` directly to output into one of the vectors. In order not to write a value before reading it, we have to proceed from the ends, like this:

```
void inmerge(vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b) {
  a.resize(a.size() + b.size());
  orig_a_rbegin = a.rbegin() + b.size();
  std::merge(orig_a_rbegin, a.rend(), b.rbegin(), b.rend(), a.rend(), [](int x, int y) { return x > y; });
}
```

It is for sure that an implementation of `merge` will never write more elements than it has read, so this is a safe thing to do. Unfortunately, the C++ standard (even C++17 draft) forbids this:

> The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original
>   ranges.

Is it okay to ignore this restriction if I know what I'm doing?

Comment: I always thought that "knowing what you are doing" leads to "following the standard".

Comment: Have you tried using `std::vector::reserve()` to deal with the allocation overhead of the back inserter? Or using `std::vector::insert()` instead?

Comment: @ypnos yes, I tried `reserve()`... now I edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: And also, using insert() instead of back_inserter() and inplace_merge is still slower than your merge call?

Comment: I didn't try that -- however, `inplace_merge` was slower than `sort`, so the copying time is not very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ignoring a mandate of the standard (or any other documentation of some library you're using) is never ok. You may know what *you* are doing, but are you sure you know what the *library* is doing - or might be doing in the next version?

For example, the merge algorithm could detect that at least two of your ranges are reverse ranges, unwrap them (and unwrap or reverse the third), and do the merge in the other direction. No observable difference as long as the preconditions are kept, but possibly a tiny bit faster since the overhead of the reverse iterators is gone. But it would really screw with your code.

Comment: The optimization in your example is not possible because the arguments to `merge` are `InputIterator`. The algorithm cannot un-reverse them.

Comment: oops, sorry, you are right. There can be a template specialization. It would be rather devilish from the library (in my opinion) but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

To state it simply: No.

A bit longer: If you ignore a mandate by the standard you end up in Undefined Behaviour land and your compiler is free to do whatever it wants. 
This includes doing exactly what you expect, doing nothing at all, crashing the program, deleting all your files or summoning nasal demons.  That's not a place you want to be.